# How to get class reference for a generic class

Tags: java, actionscript-3, class

I am new to java (coming from an Actionscript 3.0 background) and I am trying to port some actionscript code to java (as3signals to jsignal)

I am trying to get the class name of a generic class in order to pass it to a super call.

In Actionscript 3.0 this would be

```
super(Vector.<TileVO>,Boolean);
```

The above piece of code would pass the class references to the constructor for the Vector of TileVO and Boolean.

In Java this doesn't seem to work and I know I am doing something wrong:

```
super(ASVector.class<TileVO>,boolean.class);
```

To write it short, how do you get the class reference for an ASVector class composed of TileVO objects?

Thank you!

Later Edit:

I just realised that code was not displayed properly (treated as html)

Posting some source code:

```
public Signal(Class<?>... params) {
        this.params = params;
    }
```

I need to pass to the Signal class references via the constructor.

`new Signal(int.class)` for example works

I need to know how can I pass to Signal's constructor the class of an object of this form:

```
ASVector<TileVO>
```

I tried `ASVector.class<TileVO>` and it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: You appear to have a good question, but I can't really understand you. I don't know what you are meaning by "generic", and what the purpose is of passing it up. Instead of describing what you're wanting to happen, can you post the code in question (even if it's not working)?

Comment: Thank you chrylis! I believe now it's much better and you can understand what I need. I forgot to put code blocks and the editor treated <TileVO> as unrecognized html tags.

Comment: Okay, *why* are you needing to pass around class variables? What is it for? There is probably a way to accomplish your task in Java, but the idiom may be quite different from what it is in ActionScript.

Comment: I am using JSignals which is a port of as3Signals. The Signal class needs those class variables to determine the number and the type of arguments it works with and dispatch an error if it doesn't match.

https://github.com/paulmoore/Java-Signals/blob/master/src/jsignal/Signal.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At compile time, the generic type parameters `<TileVO>` in your case undergo "erasure"; the compiler converts some usage of them into implicit casts, but the information about them is discarded in the bytecode. That means that for your API, there's no specific type for `ASVector<TileVO>`, the runtime type is just `ASVector`, and so you pass in `ASVector.class`. If it's necessary for the runtime handler to know that the contents of the `ASVector` are `TileVO` objects, you'll also need to pass in `TileVO.class` as a parameter at some point in the varargs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to access `ASVector<TileVO>` as a class in Java.  In Java, there is no actual class implementation for `ASVector` with `TileVO`.  Check out the Java generics [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure):

> Java generics differ from C++ templates. Java generics generate only one compiled version of a generic class or function regardless of the number of parameterizing types used.

You *can* do something more specific to get around the issue though:

```
public static class ASVector_TileVO extends ASVector< TileVO >
{
  public ASVector_TileVO( ASVector< TileVO > objects )
  {
    super( objects );
  }
};
```

Now the `ASVector_TileVO` is a base class and can be accessed with `ASVector_TileVO.class`.